# ST_Intersects with EWKB

Tags: postgis, geodjango, well-known-text

I am working in a Django and have done a query to get a list of geometries from a table. I want to iterate through that list and insert them into my new query. My notional polygon is:

`0103000020E6100000010000000A000000C3691AE97DAB434010D59670EBAB4C40A2D701742DE041403B9994F129824C401768318F8BEE41408A0A316D2EDF4B401F6D5C4CDF0E424032402134D5854B406264439762A4424073E3BF7E573F4B40CA3E65381A4E4340391B287128384B4098C3C80CD2234440585FB4D32E374C4098C3C80CD2234440585FB4D32E374C40FE49A2AD88F143406775822944974C40C3691AE97DAB434010D59670EBAB4C40`

My latest attempt for a query is:

```
SELECT author, photo_id, user_id FROM point_database WHERE ST_Intersects(point_database.point_geom, ST_GeomFROMWKB('POLYGON(0103000020E6100000010000000A000000C3691AE97DAB434010D59670EBAB4C40A2D701742DE041403B9994F129824C401768318F8BEE41408A0A316D2EDF4B401F6D5C4CDF0E424032402134D5854B406264439762A4424073E3BF7E573F4B40CA3E65381A4E4340391B287128384B4098C3C80CD2234440585FB4D32E374C4098C3C80CD2234440585FB4D32E374C40FE49A2AD88F143406775822944974C40C3691AE97DAB434010D59670EBAB4C40)'))
```

This resulted in the less than helpful

```
 ERROR: Invalid endian flag value encountered.

SQL state: XX000
```

I know I could typically do something along the lines of ST_Intersects(point_database.geom, polygon_database.geom) but not sure how to structure a query with the ewkb hex especially when passing it through a secondary loop in a greater django framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can create your geometry without ST_GeomFROMWKB using this:

```
create table geomtest as (

    select cast(
'0103000020E6100000010000000A000000C3691AE97DAB434010D59670EBAB4C40A2D701742DE041403B9994F129824C401768318F8BEE41408A0A316D2EDF4B401F6D5C4CDF0E424032402134D5854B406264439762A4424073E3BF7E573F4B40CA3E65381A4E4340391B287128384B4098C3C80CD2234440585FB4D32E374C4098C3C80CD2234440585FB4D32E374C40FE49A2AD88F143406775822944974C40C3691AE97DAB434010D59670EBAB4C40' 
as geometry) as geom
    )
```

And can see your geometry in QGIS.

So your query might look like:

```
SELECT author, photo_id, user_id 
FROM point_database
, (
select cast('0103000020E6100000010000000A000000C3691AE97DAB434010D59670EBAB4C40A2D701742DE041403B9994F129824C401768318F8BEE41408A0A316D2EDF4B401F6D5C4CDF0E424032402134D5854B406264439762A4424073E3BF7E573F4B40CA3E65381A4E4340391B287128384B4098C3C80CD2234440585FB4D32E374C4098C3C80CD2234440585FB4D32E374C40FE49A2AD88F143406775822944974C40C3691AE97DAB434010D59670EBAB4C40' as geometry) as geom

) as poly

WHERE ST_Intersects(point_database.point_geom, poly.geom ))
```

I can't test as I don't have your other tables, but let me know if that works...

Comment: Thanks that nailed it. As my friend would say, "you da real MVP dawg".

Comment: NICE. Glad it worked!!!